# Why are extended generic types not resolving correctly?

Tags: typescript

**Summary:** The base class cannot use its properties fully when those properties are defined as an extended generic type.

**Platform:** We're currently on typescript 3.3 (3.4 is incompatible with us and 3.5 not yet released).

**Background:**
We use redux. Functions creating redux actions usually have a signature like `(x) => (dispatch, getState) => object`. In the base class of our redux components we unwrap these action-creators so they can be used directly without dispatching them: `(x) => object`.

**Problem:** Class A defines an interface PropsA, but uses a generic type extending PropsA for its props. Then these props are unwrapped and mapped. Class A can no longer use the unwrapped functions properly. I have stripped down the problem:

```js
interface PropsA {
  [x: string]: (...args: any[]) => any;

  foo(): () => string;
}

class A<props extends PropsA = PropsA> {

  actions: {
    [k in keyof props]: () => ReturnType<ReturnType<props[k]>>
  };

  constructor(protected readonly props: props) {
  }

  someMethodA(): void {
    console.log(this.props.foo()().length); //works!

    const fooResult = this.actions.foo(); //ReturnType<ReturnType<props['foo']>>
    console.log(fooResult.length); //does not work!
  }
}
```

Why is the return type known for `foo` on `this.props`, but not on `this.actions`?

When extending A, the extending class does not have this problem:

```js
interface PropsB extends PropsA {
}

class B extends A<PropsB> {

  someMethodB(): void {
    console.log(this.props.foo()().length); //works!

    const fooResult = this.actions.foo(); //ReturnType<ReturnType<PropsB['foo']>>
    console.log(fooResult.length); //it works here!
  }
}
```

Might this be a bug in typescript? Theoretically this should work. I'm telling that props is supposed to extend PropsA. So I can be sure that the props have that interface. This is what interfaces are all about. Am I wrong? Is there a different solution?

Comment: There should be a big error right at `ReturnType<props[k]>`, since you have no reason to believe that `props[k]` is a function.  Extensions of `PropsA` can have additional properties of any type whatsoever: `interface PropsC extends PropsA { bar: string, baz: boolean }`.

Comment: That's true, we have an additional index signature (`[x: string]: (...args: any[]) => any;`) to help with that, I've missed that in the example (added now). But nevertheless, the result is the same for `this.actions.foo`.